# How to call a method with no parameters which returns Expression<Func<Model, String>>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a method like this (very simplified version):

```
public static Expression<Func<MyModel, String>> GetSomeStatus()
{
    return myModel => myModel.IsTrue ? "That's true" : "That's false";
}
```

So, how can I call it in statement like this:

```
var efRequest = db.Table1.Where(...)
                            .Select(x => new MyAnotherModel
                            {
                                Status = ""; // call GetSomeStatus() here; x is of MyModel type
                            })
```

Note: My initial issue was to call some helper method which returns `String` inside `Select` method, but of course I've got exception like `Linq to entities doesn't recognize this method...`, so I've tried to rewrite it (see example above), but now I just don't understand how to call it (I'm relatively new in EF). I know about simple `AsEnumerable` call before `Select` which solves my initial issue, but I want to keep this query as `IQueryable` for later purposes.

Comment: Normally you can't. Can you use 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Ivan, I might try. If you know one, please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box. But you can use for instance [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` extension methods like this:

First you need to store the expression in a variable, otherwise you'll get the famous `Linq to entities doesn't recognize this method...` exception:

```
var getSomeStatus = GetSomeStatus();
```

and then use it inside the query (after calling `AsExpandable`, so the resulting query expression tree is correctly postprocessed):

```
var efRequest = db.Table1.AsExpandable()
    .Where(...)
    .Select(x => new MyAnotherModel
    {
        Status = getSomeStatus.Invoke(x)
    });
```